# Proof regarding the golden succession

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

Considering the golden number $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$ and the succession defined by

> $$r_n=1 +\frac 1{r_{n-1}}$$  for all $n \geq 2$ where $r_1=1$

How do I prove that $r_n=\frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}}$, where $f_n$ is the Fibonnaci sequence?

Comment: Please review any edits to ensure that the question you wish to ask is accurately reflected.

Comment: You could show it by induction on $r_n$.

Comment: Can you clarify what purpose there is in mentioning the golden ratio?  Is there some part of this question where you are getting stuck?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @abiessu is it confusing?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel but I don't have the expression for the fibonnaci sequence neither I know how to deduce it.

Comment: @abiessu i think it is needed for the other subquestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $s_n = \frac {f_n}{f_{n-1}}$

We have  $$s_n = \frac {f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}}{f_{n-1}}$$

$$= 1+\frac {f_{n-2}}{f_{n-1}} = 1 +\frac {1}{s_{n-1}}$$

Since $s_1= 1=r_1$, we have $s_n = r_n$